# Type Error: Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, typeerror

So I'm creating a new login screen that supports login, Oauth. I added some code from a generic login screen I made before but I am receiving a Type Error for my navigate prop. Can someone explain why this is occurring and how to fix it? My app won't even load up because of this error and even though the error says in APp.js: 56. Inside my app file I'm using jsx to call the logingscreen.

**LoginScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Image,
    Text,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { FontAwesome as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import FBSDK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import { ifIphoneX } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AppAuth } from 'expo';
import Footer from '../Components/Footer';
import * as userActions from '../reducers/user/Actions';
import {
    EMAIL_REGIX, //What is this EMAIL_REGIX?
    EMAIL_ALERT,
    PASSWORD_ALERT,
    PASSWORD_MESSAGE,
    FB_ALERT,
    ACCOUNT,
    FORGOT,
    SIGNUP
} from '../utils/constants';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  onSubmit = () => {
      const {
          navigation: { navigate }
      } = this.props;
      if (!EMAIL_REGIX.test(this.state.email)) {
          Alert.alert('Alert', EMAIL_ALERT);
      } else if (this.state.password.length < 6) {
          Alert.alert('Alert', PASSWORD_ALERT);
      } else if (this.state.password.length > 15) {
          Alert.alert('Alert', PASSWORD_MESSAGE);
      } else {
          navigate(ACCOUNT);
      }
  };

checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = () => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Account');
          } else {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
          }
      });
  };

render() {
  const {
      navigation: { navigate }
  } = this.props;
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill }}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/Images/TemplatePic.jpg')}
          style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null }}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: height / 3, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSubmit}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.loginbutton,
              commonStyles.alignSelfcenter,

              {
                width: width * 0.73
              }
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.logintextbutton]}>Sign In</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  },
  loginbutton: {
    width: 320,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(72, 244, 255)',
    borderRadius: 20,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 20
  },
  logintextbutton: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica-Bold'
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './config.js';
import RootStack from './RootStack';
import LoginScreen from './App/screens/LoginScreen';
import configureStore from './App/reducers/configureStore';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// create store from redux
const store = configureStore();

function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => {
    if (typeof image === 'string') {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    }
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
  });
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    // Render the app container component with the provider around it
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isReady: false
        };
      }

      async _loadAssetsAsync() {
        const imageAssets = cacheImages([
          require('./assets/images/TemplatePic.jpg'),
        ]);

        await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
      }

    render() {
      //If the state is not ready then display the apploading oterwise display the app
      if (!this.state.isReady) {
          return (
            <AppLoading
              startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
              onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
              onError={console.warn}
            />
          );
        }
      return (
        <View style={styles.background}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <LoginScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          </Provider>
        </View>
      );
    }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      background: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: 16
      },
      textStyle: {
      }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you neither dont have react-navigation installed nor you wrap your LoginScreen with createAppContainer. For navigation.navigate to work you have wrap yor screens with createAppContainer

Comment: I already have react-navigation installed yet nothing is working.

Comment: this looks fine. could you share your route or App.js code where createAppContainer locate.

Comment: Can you please add rootstack.js file ???

Answer (score 1):

In your App.js

`<LoginScreen navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>`

In your `loginScreen.js`
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () =>this.onSubmit()}>`

Also,

```
checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = () => {
const that = this;
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

          if (user) {
              that.props.navigation.navigate('Account');
          } else {
              that.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
          }
      });
  };
```

This will resolve the issue :)

You need to pass the navigation to your child component to make them accessible.

Comment: Adding this did not change the error I have. My simulator is still displaying the same error. I edited my post to showcase my current Loginscreen and app .js files.